# Performing an alphabetical sort on a vector of type structure

Tags: sorting, vector

if I have a struct

```
struct node {
  string name;
  node * next;
}
```

is it possible for me to somehow insert this data into a vector of type node
say:

`<NODE1, NODE2, NODE3, NODE4>` and then sort them alphabetically by the name they contain?

Comment: Have you tried overloading the < operator for the struct node?

Answer (score 0):

You have options to do that.

1) You can overload < operator for a struct node.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

Then you can just do a normal sort.

2) You can call a sort function with a special comparator function. This works similarly to the case 1. Read about it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/